# Difference between fault measurement and fault model

Tags: attack

In the context of fault attacks. What is the difference between fault measurement and fault model? I am reading a lecture and I can not understand for what measurement is used? Could you help me please?

Comment: Neither of these are common terms with a clearly defined meaning out of context. What's the context? I don't know of any use of “fault measurement” in cryptography. Is this an English term or a translation?

Comment: @Gilles This is obviously related to fault diagnosis and fault tolerance. Fault analysis is definitely known in the realms of cryptography and not uncommon at all  (eg [1](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2349007), [2](https://books.google.de/books?id=jkRsCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA217&ots=H6D0IRev6w&dq=cryptography%20fault%20measurement&pg=PA217#v=onepage&q=cryptography%20fault%20measurement&f=false), [3](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6318454/?reload=true), etc.). In fact, you might/should have heard about "fault measurement" in relation to side-channel, timing, and/or fault attacks.